# what is the best way to legally rent out a parking spot?

Tags: rental-property

I recently purchased a condo. Since I do not have a car, I would like to rent out the parking spot. Now, i can simply put an ad in the notice board and make a deal with some one willing to rent it.

But since the cond corp does not offer any protection in case anything goes wrong  :i.e - guy does not pay, guy does not move out  etc.....what is the best way of going about this?
Who should I talk to? A lawyer is clearly too much for this kind of thing...

Comment: In terms of protection - If someone parks in your spot (and you had your own car), you would ask the cond corp to tow them because they are parked illegally. The same would apply here, Then you will be taken to small claims by the lesee (over the bailout-fee), and you will provide proof that he has not paid or his lease has run out. Proceed to do this until he gets the message. HOWEVER, talk to your condo management. I have heard of people living in buildings with garages that have rental spots that get 80-100 knocked off their rent every month for the condo management to rent the spot out.

Answer (score 1):

Like any other rental agreement. The cond corp provides protection in case you rent out your condo? Mine doesn't...

You can get a standard rent/lease form for property rental in any office supplies store (or even on the [Internet](http://www.freelegalforms.net/FreeLegalForms.cfm?criteria=rent), choose your state).